# package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist

Tags: java, jdbc

Error in the following code ![error occured][1]

```
import java.sql.*;

public class DBConnect{
public static void main(String a[]) throws SQLException{
    // *package oracle.jdbc.driver does not exist*
    Driver d=new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
    System.out.println("Driver is registered");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have your Oracle JDBC driver in your class path?

Comment: did you add driver jar file to class path

Comment: i have dwnlded ojdbc14.jar and added this path to CLASSPATH but still the error persists

Comment: For starters, the interpretation of "classpath" is dependent on the way how exactly your program is executed. So it might be helpful if you elaborate in detail how exactly you're executing your program, so that we can tell you the right way to set the classpath. You sound like as if you've edited the environment variable `%CLASSPATH%`. This is however **ignored** when your program is executed in an IDE like Eclipse/Netbeans, or when you're executing it as a JAR file by `java -jar` command.

Comment: i have downloded the ojdbc14.jar file and placed it in the folder in which i have written this code. and in the environmental variables->system variables i have added this path as CLASSPATH. But still the error persists

Comment: yes i have edited the environmental varible %classpath% . if it is ignored how can i set the classpath then?

Comment: if your jar file and java source is in same location. Use a command prompt and changed directory to that location. and execute following

 javac -classpath ocjdbc14.jar DBConnect.java

Comment: i am not using any IDE. i will try it later

Comment: my jar file and java source file r in the same location/directory.. still the same error..

Comment: can you copy past your exception here ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to add ocjdbc jar in to your class path and try it like this.

if your jar file and java source is in same location. Use a command prompt and changed directory to that location. and execute following

```
 javac -classpath ocjdbc14.jar DBConnect.java
```

and see.

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class DBConnect{
 public static void main(String a[]) {
   try{
    Driver d=new OracleDriver();
    DriverManager.registerDriver(d);
    System.out.println("Driver is registered");
  }catch(SQLException e){
     System.out.println("Error occured "+e.getMessage());
     }
}
 }
```

Comment: Using a full qualified class name XOR using an import does not matter. Adding a jar of course might help...

Comment: Note that this isn't the idiomatic way of locaing a JDBC driver (OP's own code also not, but you should preferably not continue on the wrong idiom).

Comment: Note that OP's own code had a `throws SQLException` clause which makes the try-catch superfluous, so that's definitely not "the solution".

Answer (score 3):

You need to Add an `oracle driver jar` to the project build path,

Download [Ojdbc14.jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/mule/dependencies/maven1/oracle-jdbc/jars/ojdbc14.jar) file and put it in your classpath.

Comment: i have downloded the file ojdbc14.jar and added to my classpath but still the error persists

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following steps if you are using intellij

1. Download jdbc7 or any version
2. Add this jar on following path File>>Project Structure>>Libraries>>
   [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8YBo.png)
3. Click on Modules and add jar there too
   if you still face issue then you must see following problem 
   [Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/au8yE.png)
4. Now click on problems>>fix>>add to dependency as given below
   [Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o98af.png)
   Hope this will fix your issue

Answer (score -3):

First run the program in netbeans and add Ojdbc14.jar file into the library of the program and then it will surely execute.

After executing in NetBeans, click `Clean & Build Project...`. This will create a jar file and then path like 
`java -jar "C:\Users\s\Documents\NetBeansProjects\jdbcTest_course\dist\jdbcTest_course.jar"` will be provided.

Enter this into a command prompt (`cmd`) and it will run.

Comment: It would help if you listed the items as steps :)

Comment: Why add this answer? Why mention NetBeans? Why advise people to use an ancient Java 1.4 variant of the Oracle JDBC driver.

Comment: totally out of topic answer!