# Could not find or load main class when trying to use ojdbc

Tags: java, linux

I'm using code and compiling command from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13163715/package-oracle-jdbc-driver-does-not-exist) question (just replaced DBConnect by Test). Then I use `java -classpath ojdbc14.jar Test` and I'm getting:
`Error: Could not find or load main class Test`.

Same for:
`java -classpath "ojdbc14.jar;." Test` and `java -classpath "ojdbc14.jar;./Test.class" Test`

When I use just `java Test` then the error is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver
        at Test.main(Test.java:7)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Why `.` is there?

Comment: @KaustubhKhare since using `-cp` flag is overwriting default value which is current directory, I added it there

Comment: On linux you need to separate classpath entries using `:`, not `;`, and you don't need to surround it with quotes

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks, I don't know how I managed to miss it. Problem solved

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this,

Set the class path first and then compile and run the program.

```
classpath=%classpath%;ojdbc14.jar(path for your OJDBC jar);
javac Test.java
java Test
```